# Edit pivot table contents in Access 2013

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

I have a pivot table, say `PivotA`, and another table left joined to its primary key, say `TableB`. I need to edit `TableB` in the pivot view.

Is it possible to edit the contents of a pivot table at all? When I try to edit a cell from either source, it tells me the recordset is not updateable. It's a very vague error and I haven't found any causes relating to what I'm doing. Even if I recreate the pivot without `TableB`, I get the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An updateable record source is one that fulfills a few standards to ensure that Access knows precisely which row needs to be edited. Unfortunately, one of those limitations is that it cannot be updated in an aggregation or calculated field. I believe in most if not all cases, a pivot table is an aggregation of the underlying data. So by design, you will not be able to update data in a pivot table.

Here is a link that may help understand your error: [Updateable records](http://www.fmsinc.com/Microsoftaccess/query/non-updateable/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry hate to break it to you but the Access team decided to drop Pivot Tables in 2013. See: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc178954%28v=office.15%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

You can see a walk through of alternatives suggested by Microsoft Here: https://youtu.be/VxDWIQaO5Pg