# MS-Access, SQL, VB.NET: Use row data to create updatable pivots with unique values

Tags: ms-access, vba

I've been curious as to how to accomplish something like this:

```
tblProject
id
1
2

tblSample
id    projectID    sampleNumber
1     1            1
2     1            2 
3     1            3

tblTests
id     testName
1      test1
2      test2
3      test3

tblTestResults
id     testID   projectID  sampleID  testResults
1      1        1          1
2      2        1          1
3      3        1          1
```

I want to output the following into a datasheet:

```
projectID sampleID testID test1  test2  test3
1         1        1      entry  entry  entry
1         1        2      entry  entry  entry
1         1        3      entry  entry  entry
```

Test1, Test2, and Test3 are names from tblTests. Is there a way to automatically update the entered items underneath the test name columns? Pivoting will not allow edits. The solutions I came up with are workarounds:
1) Output the pivot into a listbox, double clicking it will load a form that has the tests.
2) Use a gridview. Load the headers: projectID, sampleID, and test names. In an array, keep track of the test name column and which testresult id it belongs to. AFter update, manually update the field.

Is there a better method?
Thank you

Comment: So, you want to create a query to combines multiple tables into one set of results, based on the value of fields that are common between the tables?

Comment: Yes. My goal is to output the joins in a way that resembles a pivot with the test names as columns but it's an editable pivot.

Comment: *Please define "**Editable***".  Do you want your users to be able to drag/drop fields around, as if it's a Pivot Table in Excel?

Comment: Also, are you aware of [Crosstab Queries](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Make-summary-data-easier-to-read-by-using-a-crosstab-query-8465b89c-2ff2-4cc8-ba60-2cd8484667e8) and how to use them?

Comment: Yes. Crosstab queries solves part of it but are read only.

Answer (score 1):

Starting with Access 2002, Microsoft upgraded Access forms to substantially improve their ability to present data in a pivot-table format. These capabilities build on features initially introduced in Access 2000 for Office Web Components.

### Programmatically creating a pivot table

Before starting to program pivot tables for Access forms, you need a reference to the Office Web Components library (`owc10.dll`). In Access 2002/2003, the library file is available in the `\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Components\10` path.  In Access 2002, the Microsoft Office XP Web Components item doesn't appear in the `References` dialog box. Therefore, you must know the path to the library file (`owc10.dll`) so that you can browse to it when specifying a reference.

### Creating a pivot table programmatically for an Access form can require several steps:

First, you need to create a form that will hold your pivot table. You can do this with the `CreateForm` method.

Next, you'll typically want to change the default name assigned to the form by the `CreateForm` method. This practice lets your Access form name reflect its role in an application.

Finally, you need to configure the active view for a pivot table on an Access form so that it organizes the data to display into appropriate row, column, and filter axes. You do this by assigning column names from an Access table or query to axes for the active view of a pivot table.

The *`Office Web Components`* object model uses terms such as `RowAxis` and `ColumnAxis` to designate axes for an active view. Any data to be organized belongs on the `DataAxis` of an active view. You can designate multiple columns of data as belonging to row, column, filter, and data axes.

## Creating a pivot table based on a table

The Access file with the samples for this article is available to download [here](http://download.microsoft.com/download/5/c/c/5cc1e311-4711-4dbd-9529-28e3520fba0b/pivottbl.exe). The file contains a form, named `frmPVTDesigner`, with five buttons. The top button, labeled `Make Orders PivotTable`, creates a simple pivot table based on the Orders table imported from the `Northwind.mdb` file. The pivot table (see the left pane in this [[image][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FxIvB.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FxIvB.jpg)) categorizes `OrderID` by `ShipCountry`. The code behind the button saves the pivot table in the `pvtOrders` form. After invoking the click event procedure for the button, you need to delete the `pvtOrders` form before you can re-run the click event procedure (or change the code in the event procedure so that it saves the new form with a different name).

With a pivot table like the one in the left pane this [[image][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FxIvB.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FxIvB.jpg), an analyst can display a count of the number of orders for each `ShipCountry`. The right panel in this [[image][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FxIvB.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FxIvB.jpg) shows that there are 16 orders with a `ShipCountry` column value of *"Argentina"*. Users can generate this subtotal by right-clicking the `OrderID` column heading in the pivot table and choosing `AutoCalc > Count`. In addition, by clicking the Hide Details button on the `PivotTable` toolbar, users can elect to suppress the display of the individual `OrderID` values so that just the counts appear.

By calling three other procedures, the Click event procedure for the top button creates a form for the pivot table, assigns the custom name `pvtOrders` to the form, and configures the pivot table. The application uses a couple of module-level variables, `strFormName` and `strRecordSource`:

```
Sub CreatePivot()

    Dim strFormName As String
    Dim strRecordSource As String

    Private Sub cmdOrdersPivotTable_Click()
    Dim strDefaultName As String

    strRecordSource = "Orders"
    strDefaultName = CreatePivotTable

    strFormName = "pvtOrders"
    If (AssignPivotTableName(strDefaultName, _
        strFormName)) = False Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ConfigureOrdersPivotTable

End Sub
```

The `CreatePivotTable` function procedure called from this code creates a new form with a RecordSource property setting equal to strRecordSource, one of the two module-level variables. You must assign a record source for a form before attempting to configure a pivot table on the form. The `CreatePivotTable` procedure assigns a value to the form's DefaultView property so that the form opens with a PivotTable view when a user opens the form from the Database window. This DefaultView setting doesn't impact how the OpenForm method of the DoCmd object opens the form.

The `CreatePivotTable` routine returns to the cmdOrdersPivotTable_Click routine the name of the new form. This name has the format Formn, where n is an integer value. After `CreatePivotTable` saves the form's settings and closes the form, cmdOrdersPivotTable_Click passes the default form name and a custom form name to AssignPivotTableName, which is another one of my functions. This function assigns a new custom name to the form for the pivot table unless the custom form name already belongs to another form in the database file. A For...Each loop searches through the members of the AllForms collection to determine whether another existing form already has the name for the new form. When the new custom form name already belongs to an existing form, the function procedure deletes the form created by `CreatePivotTable` and returns a value of False to indicate that it didn't rename the form. In this situation, cmdOrdersPivotTable_Click terminates the application. Otherwise, the AssignPivotTableName procedure successfully renames the new form and returns a value of True to `cmdOrdersPivotTable_Click`:

```
Function CreatePivotTable() As String
    Const acFormPivotTable = 3
    Dim frm1 As Access.Form

    Set frm1 = CreateForm
    frm1.DefaultView = acFormPivotTable
    frm1.RecordSource = strRecordSource

    CreatePivotTable = frm1.Name
    DoCmd.Close acForm, CreatePivotTable, _
        acSaveYes

    End Function

    Function AssignPivotTableName _
        (strDefaultName As String, _
        strFormName As String) As Boolean
    Dim acc1 As AccessObject

    AssignPivotTableName = True

    For Each acc1 In CurrentProject.AllForms
        If acc1.Name = strFormName Then
            MsgBox "Choose a form name other " & _
                "than '" & strFormName & "' that " & _
                "does not match an existing form."
            AssignPivotTableName = False
            DoCmd.DeleteObject acForm, strDefaultName
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next acc1

    DoCmd.Rename strFormName, acForm, _
        strDefaultName

End Function
```

After the application creates a form and assigns a custom name to it, the `ConfigureOrdersPivotTable` procedure assigns columns from the form's RecordSource setting to axes of the active view for the pivot table on the form. `CreatePivotTable` and `AssignPivotTableName` can be reused when creating any form for a pivot table, but the procedure for configuring a pivot table will typically be unique for each pivot table.

The configuration procedure initially opens the form for which it specifies a pivot table. Next, it uses a With...End With statement to point at the ActiveView object for the PivotTable object on the form. Inside the `With...End` With statement, the procedure successively assigns columns (in this case, ShipCountry and OrderID) to a `PivotFieldset` object (fst1). The code inside the `With...End` With statement inserts the `PivotFieldset` in an axis for the ActiveView object. ConfigureOrdersPivotTable assigns the `PivotFieldset` with the ShipCountry column to the `RowAxis` property of the ActiveView and the `PivotFieldset` with the `OrderID` column to the `DataAxis` property of the ActiveView:

```
Sub ConfigureOrdersPivotTable()

    Dim fst1 as PivotFieldset

    'Open form in PivotTable view and set
    'a reference to the form
    DoCmd.OpenForm strFormName, acFormPivotTable
    Set frm1 = Forms.Item(strFormName)

    'Set PivotTable fieldsets
    With frm1.PivotTable.ActiveView
        Set fst1 = .FieldSets("ShipCountry")
        .RowAxis.InsertFieldSet fst1
        Set fst1 = .FieldSets("OrderID")
        .DataAxis.InsertFieldSet fst1
    End With

    'Close form with its PivotTable view
    DoCmd.Close acForm, frm1.Name, acSaveYes

End Sub
```

See:

- **More information on this example is available at the [Source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa662945(v=office.11).aspx).**
- MSDN: [Form.PivotTable Property (Access)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/access-vba/articles/form-pivottable-property-access)
- Stack Overflow: [Edit pivot table contents in Access](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36630160/8112776)

Answer (score 0):

I prefer in such kind cases to use temporary tables. Copy pivot data to temp table and return back edited data after clicking Save button, few simple queries will do the job